# Baseline correction for continuous EEG signals

Tags: signal-processing, epoch, baseline

I'm new to the topic so forgive the trivial question.

I am trying to understand data preprocessing for EEG signals. As I understand, after recording continuous EEG signals, they should be band-pass filtered and segmented into epochs (so the window of time that is relevant to the experiment). After that, these epochs should be baseline corrected. Can anyone explain what this concept of baseline correction means?

Answer (score 0):

Baseline correction is the process of removing or adjusting the average signal level, which represents the underlying electrical activity unrelated to the specific experimental conditions. By correcting the baseline, any drift or offset in the signal is removed, allowing the focus on relative changes or deviations from the baseline. One approach to achieve this is by removing DC frequencies, which effectively eliminates the baseline. Techniques like high-pass filtering, detrending, or subtracting the mean of the signal can be used to remove DC frequencies and the constant component, including the baseline.